# Passing Object to parent process - C++

Tags: c++, ipc

I need to pass an object from a child process to its parent but can't when the given object is composed of templated objects.

I successfully passed a simple class to the parent process by calling write() C function giving my object's address through a socket to the parent, **but** when my object is **composed of a templated object** *(std::vector, std::pair ...)* Valgrind is giving warnings about **uninitialized bytes** and the parent process received a corrupted object.

Valgrind output :

```
==18624== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==18624==    at 0x4E4B29D: ??? (syscall-template.S:84)
```

**EDIT**:
As @Sandro suggested, I decided to serialize my complex datas (std::vector) using POD objects but without any library.

Comment: You can pass only POD types this way. For non-trivial objects there is no simple solution. You may consider using of some serialization library (google protobuf, boost serialization, etc.)